# Web API multiple GET action with different query strings

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

In my ApiController I need to handle this requests:

```
GET: api/User?role=theRole
GET: api/User?division=?theDivision
...
GET: api/User?other=stringValue
```

All these requests could be handled via a method like:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(String stringParam)
```

but obviously I cannot use overloading...

How can I solve this situation? Should I use a single method with optional parameters?

Comment: you may consider encoding all your parameters into one: `GET: api/User?stringParam=role%20theRole .....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12620238/632604 you can write your methods like this:

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
    {

        // GET api/values/5
        public string GetUsersByRole(string role)
        {
            return "Role: " + role;
        }

        public string GetUsersByDivision(string division)
        {
            return "Division: " + division;
        }
    }
```

And Web API will route the requests just like you required:

[image]

Comment: Yes, you only need to prefix the name of the method with 'Get'. The routing mechanism will use query string parameters to map to the actual method.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you could consider doing would be modifying the default routes in your WebApiConfig file, you'll see how the default route is set as

`routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API Default",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);`

Change this to

`routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "API Default",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );`

You could then tag each web API action with the correct HTTP action such as [HttpGet]. To learn more about routing and handling multiple HTTP actions in Web API take a look at http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api