# Force questionmark to show in querystring where only ID param is passed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, query-string

I've implemented code to encrypt my query string parameter names and values. The code i have implemented will only encrypt query string that contain `?`. (This is to prevent encryption of unneeded URL's, such as the `.css` files).

A way to combat this would be to always show the `?` in query strings when only the ID parameter is passed.

For example I would like: http://domain/controller/Action/17

To show as: http://domain/controller/Action/?id=17

I understand that I probably need to edit my routes, I've tried adding the `?` symbol to the route which throws the error `: The route URL cannot start with a '/' or '~' character and it cannot contain a '?' character.`

My routes are defined as:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

How can I get my query strings to show like the example given above?

Comment: Change as below,

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619587/routing-based-on-query-string-parameter-name

Comment: I removed the {id} from the route and now i get Server Error in Application as it tries to browse to http://domain/controller/

Comment: Thanks @Thennarasan will check out the link

Answer (score 2):

Don't define your parameters in `routes`.

ASP.NET automaticaly will add the question mark.

You can then call http://domain/controller/Action?id=17 and it will route to

```
public ActionResult Action(int id) { }
```

**Update:** If you want to kill `domain/controller/action/id` format completely, you need to define the route as:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Parameterless", //or any name
   url: "YourController",
   defaults: new { controller = "YourController", action = "YourAction" }
);
```

Now you can use `domain/controller/action?id={id}` and `domain/controller/action/id` will 404.

If you are getting a `Server Application Error`, you need to provide more details, since it might be related to something else.

Comment: I removed the {id} from the route and now i get `Server Error in Application` as it tries to browse to `http://domain/controller/`

Comment: You can keep the default definition.
What happens when you default to `{controller}/{action}/{id}` and try to call `domain/controller/Action?id=17` ?

Comment: Sorry we can ignore the first route as this is for a different controller. I will take it out of my question. When I default to the above and browse to the link it works as expected, however I would like the above query string to be entered into the URL every time, instead of `domain/controller/action/17`. If you get what I mean

Comment: Just tested it. If you want to kill `domain/controller/action/17` for good, remove the `/{id}` part from `{controller}/{action}/{id}` with `, id = UrlParameter.Optional` section from defaults too, it works as you want. I'll update my answer.

Comment: It stops me being able to browse to that link, but it also causes a `Server Error in '/' Application` when I then click a button which calls the action. To be honest I'm not even sure it's possible to do what I'm asking

Comment: It's not as such I want to "use" `domain/controller/action?id={id}` it's that I want that format to always show in the URL as oppose to `domain/controller/action/id`. This is not by me typing the URL myself but by button click which calls an action

Comment: After quite a bit of research i don't think this is possible

Comment: Oh, you want your other links to be redirected that way?

Comment: You can always type your button redirections by hand and avoid using the helper method. If you `<a href="@("domain/controller/action?id=" + @model.Id)" />` it should redirect you to the url you want.

Comment: Good point - I could do that, however my solution is huge so looking for something quicker and a more global solution

Comment: I doubt that would be solved with routing only since `?` is a reserved character. I might only suggest you to `CTRL + SHIFT + H` to do a replace all.